# AND query a m-to-n table

Tags: sql, database, layout, sqlite

I have a simple m-to-n table in a database and need to perform an AND search. The table looks as follows:

```
column a | column b
1          x
1          y
1          z
2          x
2          c
3          a
3          b
3          c
3          y
3          z
4          d
4          e
4          f
5          f
5          x
5          y
```

I want to be able to say 'give me column A where it has x AND y in column b (returning 1 and 5 here), but i can't figure out how to form that query.

I tried `SELECT column_a FROM table WHERE column_b = x AND columb_b = y` but it seems that would only return if the column was somehow both. Is it fundamentally possible, or should i have a different table layout?

Comment: please specify tag your DBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT a
FROM Table1
WHERE b IN ('x', 'y')
GROUP BY a
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(b)) = 2
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ca9a/1)

If you are guaranteed (a,b) is unique, you can get rid of the DISTINCT as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" subquery.  I like to use `group by` and put the logic in the `having` clause:

```
select column_a
from table
group by column_a
having sum(case when column_b = x then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when column_b = y then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The each `sum()` in the `having` clause is counting the number of rows that match one of the conditions.

This turns out to be quite general.  So, you can check for `z` just by adding a clause:

```
select column_a
from table
group by column_a
having sum(case when column_b = x then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when column_b = y then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when column_b = z then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Or, make it "x" or "y" by using `or` instead of `and`:

```
select column_a
from table
group by column_a
having sum(case when column_b = x then 1 else 0 end) > 0 or
       sum(case when column_b = y then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it *fundamentally* possible?  Yes.  The easiest way to see why this would be is to look at the quick and dirty solution, using an INTERSECT:

```
select a from your_table where b = 'x'
intersect
select a from your_table where b = 'y'
```

The first clause returns 1, 2, and 5; the second returns 1, 3, and 5.

However, in practice, it is better to use grouping, as in the other answers.